# How can I redirect/catch the "git" command and do some things before the real git command?

Tags: bash, git, shell, zsh

actually I am writing this function linked in my zshrc:

```
function mgit {
  string='github'
  remote=$(git remote -v)
  if [[ ${remote} == *${string}* ]]; then
    git config --global user.name "name1"
    git config --global user.email "email1@test.com"
  else
    git config --global user.name "name2"
    git config --global user.email "email2@test.de"
  fi
  git "$@"
}
```

This works fine if I now execute `mgit --version` instead `git --version`.

But is there a way to catch the real git command and execute this function?
Because now i cant use my aliases e.g. `ga` for `git add .`...
And is it then possible with all commands like docker or something else?

Comment: One way is to set an alias in .zshrc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Just call your function `git` and use `command git` to call the "real" `git`:

```
git() {
  echo "Do some things"
  command git "$@"
}
```

Example:

```
% git --version
Do some things
git version 2.19.2
```

Comment: good idea, but then my zsh shell crashes - I think because I have the git plugin? so perhaps there is another way?

Comment: How does it crash? Make sure the function does not have any `git` commands without `command` in front of it, since that would be infinite recursion